# How to remove one of the Item in Roles.GetAllRoles()

Tags: c#, membership-provider

I have a collection of Roles.GetAllRoles() on Membership Providers. Now I have one role "System Administrator" that I would like to remove from that list so I can use in my list. How do I do this?

```
public void AssignUserToRoles_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AvailableRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles();
                AvailableRoles.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It can achieved without adding any extra lines to your code.

```
public void AssignUserToRoles_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AvailableRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles().Except(new [] {"System Administrator"});
                AvailableRoles.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

Comment: not sure why do you need try...catch here. But whatever, this solution looks neat to me.

Comment: Can not do this either: Roles.GetAllRoles().Except(new [] {"System Administrator"}); 

No methods for Except ?!!?

Comment: "using System.Linq".
I thought this was obvious. This is an extension method in "System.Core" dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted you could use LINQ to convert the array into a list...

```
var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList();
roles.Remove("Administrator"); //Yank out the admin role...

AvailableRoles.DataSource = roles;
AvailableRoles.DataBind();
```

All your databinding will work just fine with a `List<String>`

**UPDATE:**

`ToList<T>()` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_members.aspx) that is part of the .Net 3.5 bundle. You need to make sure your project is targeting that framework version, and you need to make sure your project has a reference to System.Core.

Once you have that reference you need to add a `Using` statement at the top of the file your code is located at:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you have all those those things, then you should start seeing a bunch of new extension methods show up in intellisense.

Comment: This is weird. I don't get the ToList() after Roles.GetAllRoles() ?!?!

Comment: @dewacorp: data binding works with collection interfaces, including IEnumnerable<T>, not just concrete collection types.

Answer (score 0):

**Roles.GetAllRoles()** returns a *string array* which you can filter using this code:

```
        string[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        var v = from role in roles
                where role != "System Administrator"
                select role;

        AvailableRoles.DataSource = v;
        AvailableRoles.DataBind();
```